# Trying to select last row and column in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have been stuck on this for the longest time and it is probably an easy fix I am not seeing. I am trying to select that last row of a table and create a border around it up until the last column. "POS" is the name of the worksheet I am working in. "BRangePOS" is me saying this is where the table begins.

Here is my code.

```
Set BRangePOS = POS.Range("A1")
    With BRangePOS
        With POS
            lrowPOS = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            lcolPOS = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        End With
    End With

    POS.Range(lrowPOS, lcolPOS).BorderAround Weight:=xlMedium
```

The error I get is a "Method ' Range' of Object_'Worksheet' Failed"

Any help would be great.

Thanks,

G

Comment: Range needs to be an area, not a single cell

Comment: Look at [this tutorial](https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/find-last-row-column-cell/) and use the .Find method. There are images to make it easier to understand. Or use other method, but read to know more about last row/column/cell

Comment: Is it only the last row that requires a border around it?  i.e. Not the entire table? You mention this is a Pivot Table.  Why not just apply one of the existing Pivot Table Styles -- eg PivotLight28 has a border around the last row; and there may be other interesting styles.

Comment: You can also create your own or modify a Pivot Table Style to get what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a border around the last row of a table :

```
Dim POS As Worksheet
Dim BRangePOS As Range
Dim LastRow, LastCol As Integer
Dim ColStart, RowStart As Integer

Set POS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("POS")            ' Working sheet

' ------- Where the table starts - to input [xx] -------
Set BRangePOS = POS.[a1]                              '|
' ------------------------------------------------------

ColStart = BRangePOS.Column                     ' Column start
RowStart = BRangePOS.Row                        ' Row Start
LastRow = BRangePOS.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count    ' Number  of rows
LastCol = BRangePOS.CurrentRegion.Columns.Count ' Number of columns

POS.Range(Cells(LastRow + RowStart - 1, BRangePOS.Column), _
    Cells(LastRow + RowStart - 1, LastCol + ColStart - 1)). _
    BorderAround Weight:=xlMedium
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below:

```
Sub test()


Set BRangePOS = POS.Range("A1")

        With POS
            lrowPOS = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            lcolPOS = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        End With

    POS.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lrowPOS, lcolPOS)).BorderAround Weight:=xlMedium

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, it did not work. I did not get an error message but there is no border around the last row. Is it worth mentioning that this is a pivot table?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can get some ideas from this.
To find the last row:

```
lastRow = findLastRow("Sheet1", "A:A") ' Or "A:X"

Function findLastRow(Sheetname As String, ColumnName As String) As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim r As Range
    Dim WS As Worksheet

    Set WS = Worksheets(Sheetname)
    lastRow = WS.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    '*
    '* Search backwards till we find a cell that is not empty
    '*
    Set r = WS.Range(ColumnName).Rows(lastRow)
    While IsEmpty(r)
        Set r = r.Offset(-1, 0)
    Wend
    lastRow = r.Row
    Set WS = Nothing
    findLastRow = lastRow
End Function
```

Add function for columns if neeeded

Comment: Avoid implicit references (workbook at Set WS). Why not pass the range object as argument?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `<range>.End()` - these also help cater for the edge cases where your table only has one column or one row. The following code snippet selects the last row of the table starting at `BRangePOS`:

```
Dim startOfLastRow As Range
Set startOfLastRow = BRangePOS.End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlUp)

With Range(startOfLastRow, startOfLastRow.End(xlToRight).End(xlToRight).End(xlToLeft))
  'Insert code to apply border here
End With
```